# Categorizing variables in SAS

Tags: sas

Create a new variable (BMICAT) in the aisdat data frame that appropriately categorizes each indiv using computed BMI. Print Sex, Sport, BMI, and BMICAT for the first 5 rows of data.

I can't get BMICAT to print. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data aisdat;
input Sex $ Sport $ Htm2 Wt;
BMI=Wt/Htm2;
if (BMI < 18.5) then BMICAT='Underweight';
else if (BMI > 18.5) and (BMI < 24.99) then BMICAT='Normal';
else if (BMI > 24.99) and (BMI < 29.99) then BMICAT='Overweight';
else if (BMI >= 29.99) then BMICAT='Obese';
datalines;
F BBall 3.837681 78.9
F BBall 3.598609 74.4
F BBall 3.161284 69.1
F BBall 3.4225 74.9
F BBall 3.407716 64.6
F BBall 3.0276 63.7
F BBall 3.467044 75.2
F BBall 3.020644 62.3
F BBall 2.937796 66.5
F BBall 3.236401 62.9
;

PROC PRINT data=aisdat (obs=5);
var BMI BMICAT;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

Comment: This maybe off topic, but I can't help pointing out: 1. You have gaps in your value assignment. Value of exact 18.5 and 24.99 is not covered. 2. You get lucky 'underweight' is your first assignment. Swap 'Normal' or 'Obese' to the first assignment and see what will happen. It is a good practice to always use Length statement instead of using value itself to define length.

Answer (score 0):

For those that experience the same difficulties, I have found the answer:

Delete the var name.

Comment: VAR specifies the variables to be printed. Your output should have included only those two variables. Not specifying the VAR statement means all print by default.

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work.  I didn't have any problem getting BMICAT to print using your code with no changes.  I did change your inequality statements to be inclusive of all values. See below. Also, although not strictly needed, a run statement after the Data step is good practice.  Since your question said to print all the other variables, I modified it as well.

Lastly, @Haikuo Bian had a good point.  Sas will define BMICAT length based on the length of the first value it assigns. Since Underweight is 11 characters and is the longest, I've included an informat statement to prevent future angst from truncation of subsequent assignments to BMICAT.

```
data aisdat;
input Sex $ Sport $ Htm2 Wt;
informat BMICAT $11.;
BMI=Wt/Htm2;
if (BMI < 18.5) then BMICAT='Underweight';
else if (BMI >= 18.5) and (BMI < 25) then BMICAT='Normal';
else if (BMI >= 25) and (BMI < 30) then BMICAT='Overweight';
else if (BMI >= 30) then BMICAT='Obese';
datalines;
F BBall 3.837681 78.9
F BBall 3.598609 74.4
F BBall 3.161284 69.1
F BBall 3.4225 74.9
F BBall 3.407716 64.6
F BBall 3.0276 63.7
F BBall 3.467044 75.2
F BBall 3.020644 62.3
F BBall 2.937796 66.5
F BBall 3.236401 62.9
;
RUN;*GOOD PRACTICE*;
PROC PRINT data=aisdat (obs=5);
var sex sport bmi bmicat;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

Output from this:

```
Obs Sex Sport BMI BMICAT 
1 F BBall 20.5593 Normal 
2 F BBall 20.6747 Normal 
3 F BBall 21.8582 Normal 
4 F BBall 21.8846 Normal 
5 F BBall 18.9570 Normal
```